# I want to place the clock in the center

Tags: java, jframe

I was allowed to place a watch and a button in `JFrame`. When the full-screen display , the watch did not come to the center.
How can it be placed a clock in the center do?

**My source**

```
package clock;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.*; 

public class FullScreenExample
{   
    static class GameFrame extends JFrame  //
    {

        private static final GraphicsDevice gd = (GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices())[0];
        private static final boolean FULLSCREEN_SUPPORTED = gd.isFullScreenSupported();
        private static final String MAKE_FULLSCREEN_TEXT = "Full Screen";
        private static final String MAKE_WINDOWED_TEXT = "Window";
        private static final int WINDOWED_WIDTH = 400;
        private static final int WINDOWED_HEIGHT = 300;

        JPanel clock = new Clock();

        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        private final JButton fsButton = new JButton(MAKE_FULLSCREEN_TEXT);

        private boolean isFullscreen = false;

        public GameFrame(String title)
        {
            super(title);
            setSize(WINDOWED_WIDTH, WINDOWED_HEIGHT);
            setLocation((screenSize.width - 300) / 2, (screenSize.height -300)/2);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            initComponents();
        }

        public void initComponents()
        {
            if(FULLSCREEN_SUPPORTED)
            {
                fsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {       
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        toggleFullscreen();
                    }
                });

                add(fsButton,BorderLayout.NORTH);
                add(clock);
            }
            else
            {
                add(new JLabel("full screen X"));
            }
        }

        public void toggleFullscreen()
        {
            isFullscreen = !isFullscreen;
            setVisible(false);
            dispose();
            setUndecorated(isFullscreen);

            if(isFullscreen)
            {
                fsButton.setText(MAKE_WINDOWED_TEXT);
                gd.setFullScreenWindow(this);
                clock.setLocation((screenSize.width) / 2, (screenSize.height )/2);

                validate();
            }
            else
            {
                fsButton.setText(MAKE_FULLSCREEN_TEXT);
                gd.setFullScreenWindow(null);
                setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }


    static class Game
    {
        private GameFrame gameFrame;  //

        public Game(String title)
        {
            gameFrame = new GameFrame(title); //
        }

        public void start()
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    getGameFrame().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        public GameFrame getGameFrame()  //
        {
            return gameFrame;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Game g = new Game("Clock");
        g.start();        
    }
}


class Clock extends JPanel{
    private JTextField timeField;
    private Timer t;

    public Clock() {

            timeField = new JTextField(9);

            timeField.setEditable(false); 
            timeField.setFont(new Font("sansserif", Font.PLAIN,50));

            add(timeField);

            t= new Timer(1000, new ClockListener()); 

            t.start();

        }

        private class ClockListener implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){

            Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance(); 

            int hour = time.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            int amPm  = time.get(Calendar.AM_PM);   

              String strAmPm = null;
              if(amPm == Calendar.AM) 
                strAmPm = "  AM";
              else 
                strAmPm = "  PM";

            int min = time.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            int sec = time.get(Calendar.SECOND);

            timeField.setText(strAmPm + " " + hour + " : " + min + " : " + sec);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` by default

Answer (score 0):

By default, the JPanel will use the FlowLayout. This layout will basically just stack components side by side as long as they fit. You want to set your layout to a BorderLayout. This is how you would implement that:

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

You tried to set fsButton to BorderLayout.NORTH, but you haven't set the layout. You will need to use BorderLayout.CENTER when adding your clock. This obviously will make it centered. This is what it looks like:

```
add(clock, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Thanks for the read! Hope this helps.